# Use of the word "through": she kept staring at me through all the classes

Tags: word-usage

Consider the scenario where my friend had a fight with a girl. That girl then kept staring at me as if I had caused that fight. We (that girl and I) had all of our classes together.

> She kept staring **at me through all the classes**.
>   (That's because we had all our classes together.)

Is the use of "through" natural?

("She kept staring at me all the time.")

Answer (score 3):

"Through" can be used in a temporal sense, so there is nothing technically wrong with it. However, the word "throughout" would have an explicit temporal quality to it in the circumstances, so would perhaps be a better option.

Comment: Will it be something like: "She kept staring at me throughout all the classes."

Comment: And will "through" be likely?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish to the former question; yes, that's entirely unambiguous (albeit slightly stilted)

Comment: So if it sounds stilted, is there a better way to express it?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish not really related to the original question you asked, but perhaps something like "For all the classes throughout the rest of that day she constantly stared at me"